# I'll come sometime end of March

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct:

> I'll come sometime end of March.

The expected meaning should be, I'll come end of march but exact date is not known yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost, but it's missing a preposition and article. You should say

> I'll come sometime **at the** end of March.

Comment: Not that dropping prepositions is altogether wrong: 'I'll see you Friday [sometime]'. But this example sounds nearer to journalese than conversational deletion, and is better with the 'at the', as you say.

Comment: @edwinashworth - not disagreeing with you per se as it is better in written form with 'at the'. However, I would say simply '... end of March' in conversation.

Comment: Yeah, this is just how I would write it. Obviously your mileage may vary in actual conversation.

Comment: @Jascol Google hits for "see you at the end of May" heavily outnumber those for "see you end of May"; the ratio is about 8 : 1. The deleted form sounds over-clipped to my (British) ears for other than journalese, textspeak etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm pretty much in the same boat. Main reason I mentioned the preposition/article is that it sounds like part of the sentence was cut off without it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I understand, but that is how you would write it - so obviously it outnumbers the clipped form. I was just saying that is how I would say/speak it (as a British person), at least in an informal environment. Edit: I wonder actually if it is an age thing? For the record I am under 30.

Comment: @Jascol So my views are over twice as ... erm.... A look on Google Ngrams should show trends, though (but mainly for written examples).